# How to get THIS of each jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have got following function but

```
  $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').each(function () {
```

gives me different **THIS** that I need. It gives **THIS** that comes from

```
 $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').click(function () {
```

My question is how to get **THIS** of `.each(function` ?

Thank you!

```
function EnableButton()
    {
        $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').click(function () {

            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            }

            $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) { // I need THIS of --- .each(function
                    $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', false);
                }
                else {
                    $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$('input[id^="ProductId_"]').not(this).each(...)`?

Comment: What is this code trying to do? It makes alarm bells go off all over my head. There is so much duplication that the first thing you should do is rewrite it to be simpler.

Comment: Yeah, this code doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want the `this` in the `.each()` to be the same as ouside, then what's the point of the loop?

Comment: The only thing I *think* you need in your `click` handler is: `$("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'));` -- but I really hope you're not reusing `id="sendBtn"` in your HTML. I'm sorry, but your question as written isn't making enough sense to us.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is code I finally found that helps enable/disable button depending if some of checkboxes are checked.

```
function EnableButton()
    {

        $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').click(function () {

            var self = this;
            if ($(self).prop('checked')) {
                $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            }

            var areEnabledCheckboxes = false;
            $('input.ProductCheckbox').each(function (index, value) {
                 if ($(value).prop('checked')) {
                     areEnabledCheckboxes = true;
                 }                 
            });

            if (areEnabledCheckboxes) {
                $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else {
                $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Check out @billyonecan for a much neater answer

Comment: @yuvi His solution does not work at all. My solution does what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Don't be offended. Maybe he haven't tested it, but that's definitly the direction you're looking for - your solution is very repetitive and not very efficient (at the very least, do `var btn = $('#sendBtn')` and use that instead of jQuery-ing it every time)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make sense to attach a `click` handler inside of a function like this. Each time you invoke `EnableButton()`, you're attaching an additional click handlers.

I'm not entirely sure what it is that you're trying to do, because the code doesn't really make sense. If you look at it, `#sendBtn`'s `disabled` property is going to be set according to the `checked` state of the last element in the loop.

I'm guessing that you're trying to set the property based on whether or not any of your `inputs` are checked or not, in which case you can do:

```
var $input = $('input[id^="ProductId_"]');

$input.on('change', function() {
    $('#sendBtn').prop('disabled', !$input.filter(':checked').length);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need that `each` at all? 
It's simpler to bind everything directly to the click:

```
function EnableButton() {
    $('input[id^="ProductId_"]').click(function() {
        $("#sendBtn").prop('disabled', !this.disabled);
    });
}
```

Comment: Or `!this.disabled` to make it shorter and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache a reference to `this` at any point and refer back to it.

```
var self = this
```

Comment: While your solution is technically right, take a look at its application to the code provided. Does it make sense to you?